# Compute integral using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

$\oint_C 2xydx + [(1-y)z+x^2+x]dy + (\frac{x^2}{2} + e^z)dz$,

where $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, $z\ge0$ with cone $z^2=x^2+(y-1)^2$.

Although I managed to compute it sketching the graph, I don't understand why this happens when the algebraic path is taken for finding the intersection curve:

$x^2=1-y^2$

$z^2=x^2 + (y^2-2y+1)\rightarrow z^2=(1-y^2) + (y^2-2y+1)$

$z^2= 2 - 2y$

$y = -\frac{z^2}{2} + 1, z\ge0.$

This curve is supposed to be closed. What is the mistake here?

Comment: The condition $x^2=1-y^2$ implicitly means $-1\leq y\leq 1$, meaning $0<z\leq 2$. Your parametrization then is two-fold $\gamma_{\pm}(z)=(\pm \sqrt{1-(1-z^2/2)^2}, 1-z^2/4,z)$. Note that $\gamma_{\pm}(0)=(0,1,0)$ and $\gamma_{\pm}(2)=(0,-1,2)$: two paths from $(0,1,0)$ to $(0,-1,2)$.

Comment: By the way, a better parametrization of this curve is: $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \sqrt{2(1-\sin \theta)})$ which makes it completely apparent that this is a closed path.

Comment: $-1\leq y\leq 1$ and the curve is  symmetric with respect to the plane yOz